# When it's used the OutOfProcees hosting model configuration on .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I'm studying the .NET Core environment and I know what is the main process o Inprocess and OutOfProcess, but I'm not sure which one is used for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Hosting Model used to deploy your application in the project file. There is this configuration called **AspNetCoreHostingModel** which can be set as **InProcess** or **OutofProcess**.

[image: .csproj file]

The main difference between the two is InProcess use only one web server while OutofProcess uses two web servers, one as a reverse proxy to host applications. And further you can achieve a better performance with InProcess hosting.

Comment: Wich one of then would it be the normal one for production?

Comment: Using InProcess would be ideal for production